# Has somebody built a navigation/menu helper for Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, helper

I see there is [one for staticmatic](http://staticmatic.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/contrib/helpers/navigation_helper.rb),
and plenty in the [Ruby toolbox for rails menu builders](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_menu_builders.html),
but I can't seem to track one down specifically for Sinatra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no, there is no menu helper for sinatra.
You can look at all the libraries and extensions for sinatra at [Sinatra in the Wild](http://www.sinatrarb.com/wild) (scroll about halfway down the page). There is also the [Padrino Framework](http://www.padrinorb.com/), which builds on Sinatra by adding more functionality. That is probably where something you are looking for is most likely to appear.

Comment: Thanks, missed the /wild link in the docs, thats a great resource, and Padrino looks tight, thanks for the "no".

Comment: No problems, I was looking for something similar recently.

Answer (score 1):

The popular [simple-menu](http://rubygems.org/gems/simple-navigation) gem works with Sinatra as well as Rails.